# How can I get the size of the stack frame used by a FnOnce object?

Tags: rust

The [`stacker`](https://docs.rs/stacker/0.1.14/stacker/index.html) crate provides a function that can optionally run a closure on a newly allocated stack.

```rust
pub fn maybe_grow<R, F: FnOnce() -> R>(
    red_zone: usize, stack_size: usize, f: F) -> R
```

> This function will check to see if we’re within `red_zone` bytes of the end of the stack, and if so it will allocate a new stack of at least `stack_size` bytes.
>
> The closure `f` is guaranteed to run on a stack with at least `red_zone` bytes, and it will be run on the current stack if there’s space available.

I am wondering if there is any way to get the size of the stack frame used by `f` so that we can guarantee for sure that the `red_zone` will be larger, rather than using some heuristic value for `red_zone`.

For example, I would like to have an implementation of `stack_frame_size<F>(f: &F) -> usize` such that I can perform the following.

```rust
pub fn safely_grow<R, F: FnOnce() -> R>(
    stack_size: usize, f: F) -> R {
    let sf_size = stack_frame_size(&f);

    // Always make sure that the remaining stack size
    // is greater than what we need by a margin.
    maybe_grow(sf_size + 32, stack_size, f)
}
```

Is this possible and how to implement it?

Comment: you want to calculated the stack needed ? that impossible, if it would rustc and every compiler would do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, this is not possible. Consider a simple `FnOnce()` which calls some other function `MaybeRecursive()`, which in turn calls itself based on some condition determined during execution. Such a `FnOnce()` may grow its stack frame to infinity (failing at that in practice) or it might return immediately. Determining the stack frame size would require pre-computing that `FnOnce()` at compile-time given the parameters at runtime, which is infeasible in practice. The [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) lurks underneath.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the stack space taken by each invocation of `MaybeRecursive` should not be counted into the `FnOnce` object's stack frame, they are `MaybeRecursive`s'. Definition of stack frame: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: What if `MaybeRecursive` gets inlined? What about LTO?

Comment: If a function is inlined, then it should contribute to the caller's stack frame. If an recursive function is inlined, then the recursion is transformed to a loop, so the stack frame of it will not be infinite. But I don't know how to deal with LTO. Good point!